# How to include "npm install && npm run dev" command in laravel-sail

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-sail

I'm trying to include "npm install && npm run dev" command in my sail docker-compose file,
so that developers and tester don't have to run then each time starting work or switching branches
How can I achive it? here's what I tried
I'm using webserver to serve php at localhost:80
and using frontend to serve vite,(js files) at 5173

```
services:
    webserver:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            # - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
            IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH: '${PWD}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - frontend
            - mailpit

    frontend:
        image: sail-8.2/app
        command: "npm install && npm run dev"
        ports:
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
            IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH: '${PWD}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
```

Comment: There are several possibilities. Think "entrypoint" and think "multiple commands": ```entrypoint: [ "bash", "-c", "chmod +x /scripts/npm.sh && sh /scripts/npm.sh"]``` maybe you cab rub those npm commands in that same `bash -c` instead of calling that bash script

Comment: As I webserver already has it's entrypoint, I tried with entrypoint in frontend container,
It's working also but js files are not loading in browser.

Comment: You'll have to look at a lot of things. Keep updating your original question with all the information you give in the replies to comments. Look at `vite`. npm run dev starts vite? webpack? Run your commands inside the container, will your .js files show up then? Deliver. Js and .css files in your project repository? Or does the developer have to develop on those files? It all depends on what you want to deliver.

Comment: Those commands should probably go into a custom Dockerfile, in an image built `FROM node`.